# Can Database Changes be propagated to Code First Models

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first

I've been practicing the Code First concept on my database. Since I have worked with databases longer than .NET Code Development, I tend to always consider ways to leverage the power of the database and so my standard practice has always been Database first and then use an ORM like EF to generate the context for the DAL.

So please excuse if this may seem like a stupid question. I've been getting accustomed to using the Code Migration utility to create my primary and foreign key relationships, define Primary Keys and etc. Great learning experience but for some tasks I think it is better to simply go straight to the database and run a script. Such as creating check constraints, stored procedures to implement as functions in code and etc.

So my question is, if I perform a task like creating a check constraint in the database is there any way to propagate the change to the code first model? I know the update-migration command will force changes in the model to the database so as I am a beginner to this method I am wondering how can I get Code First to receive changes in the database as opposed to pushing changes out.

I ask because everything I've learned so far seem to enforce the term "Code First" as if when you begin developing in this mode, you cannot reverse the logic if needed.

Is this right or am I simply missing something???

Also, is it considered a common or reasonable practice to use Code First and EF? Seems as though Code First provides the same benefits as EF and so it would seem to be a redundant use of code.

Comment: No, code-first is really code-first. Actually, this is one of the things that makes me reluctant to use it. There are many things that code-first can't create in the database and I hate to mix migration code and raw SQL. Moreover, I don't know what happens when features we have to add manually now will be supported later. You'd somehow have to add them to the migration history.

Comment: Thank you Gert. I kinda had a feeling that this would be the answer but just wasn't absolutely certain and was really hoping to the contrary. Thanks for the information. All things considered at this point, I'll have to chalk this one up to a learning experience and I am going back to the Database First model.